# how to add data to a table in sqlite 3 without going to a new line

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x

I'm using sqlite to hold a series of data about stocks such as buy price, sell price, trend buy price etc.
I add the prices and thats fine but when I add the trends it goes on to a new line, how do I add this in line with the other data?
I have tried using replace and update but it still adds on causing my other columns to return none which is causing problems with my code.

My code is as follows

```
def plot():
    for a in stock:
        count1 = 0
        count2 = 1
        index = 0
        value = ["0"]
        cursor.execute("""SELECT BuyPrice FROM """+a+"""""")
        trend = []
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            print(row[0])
            trend.append(float(row[0]))
            index = index + 1
            if index == len(web):
                percentage = []
                for i in range(len(web)-1):
                    change = trend[count2]-trend[count1]
                    print(trend[count2],trend[count1])
                    percent = (change/trend[count1])*100
                    print(percent)
                    percentage.append(percent)
                    count1 = count1 + 1
                    count2 = count2 + 1
                for i in percentage:
                    print(i)
                    if i <= 0:
                        if i == 0:
                            value.append(0)
                        elif i <= -15:
                            value.append(-4)
                        elif i <= -10:
                            value.append(-3)
                        elif i <= -5:
                            value.append(-2)
                        elif i < 0:
                            value.append(-1)
                    else:
                        if i >= 15:
                            value.append(4)
                        elif i >= 10:
                            value.append(3)
                        elif i >= 5:
                            value.append(2)
                        elif i >= 0:
                            value.append(1)

                for i in value:
                    t = str(i)
                    cursor.execute("""
                        REPLACE INTO """+ a +"""
                        (TrendBuy)
                        VALUES
                        ("""+ t +""")
                        """)
```

[this is what i mean if its a bit hard to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkwC1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite's [`REPLACE INTO`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-statement/) needs a sort of "lookup column" to find a value and then replace the next corresponding value(s). If no matches exist, it will insert a new row. Consider incorporating *BuySell* in your action query. Also below formats SQL string and parameterizes query:

```
cursor.execute("REPLACE INTO {} (BuySell, TrendBuy) VALUES (?, ?)".format(a), (row[0], t))
```

Alternatively, you could run an update query to avoid unintentional inserts and since no new *BuySell* values generate in looping logic.

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE {} SET TrendBuy = ? WHERE BuySell = ?".format(a), (t, row[0]))
```

*Aside - you seem to be storing each Stock in its own table. For efficiency, scalability, and easier querying, consider one Stock table with a StockName or Symbol column.*